# Making ajax calls to third party APIs in ionic services.js file?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, ionic-framework

Started using ionic today and ran into a small bump.
The services.js file has a comment
`// Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array`

I want to make an ajax call to an API but I don't know how do declace a custom resource in that services.js file. 
I will receive a JSON array from that call and will work with the list thre on.

Question: How do I declare a custom variable as a list which makes an ajax call to a third pary API?

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Chats', function() {
// Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array
 var popularURL = 'SOME_API_RUL';
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    var chats = xhttp.responseText;
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", popularURL, true);
xhttp.send();

return {
  all: function() {
    return chats;
  },
  remove: function(chat) {
    chats.splice(chats.indexOf(chat), 1);
  },
  get: function(chatId) {
  for (var i = 0; i < chats.length; i++) {
    if (chats[i].id === parseInt(chatId)) {
      return chats[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
  }
};
```

The chats list is never populated. How do a correctly make an ajax call inside the ionic services.js file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Chats', function($http) {

  var API_URL = 'https://api.herokuapp.com';

  return {
    all: function() {
      return $http.get(API_URL + '/chats');
    }
  };
});
```

And in the controller:

```
Chats.all().then(function(chats){
  $scope.chats = chats;
})
```

You can check [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) in the docs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mati Tucci. I will post a more detailed awnser here.

Steps:

1. Declare what controller you want to use in the view inside the app.js file. In my case:

   ```
   .state('tab.popular', {
     url: '/popular',
     views: {
       'tab-popular': {
         templateUrl: 'templates/tab-popular.html',
         controller: 'PopularShowsCtrl' //<---CONTROLLER NAME YOU ARE USING
       }
     }
   })
   ```
2. Declare a controller in the controllers.js file. In my case:

   ```
   .controller('PopularShowsCtrl', function($scope, PopularShows){
      $scope.popShows = PopularShows.all(); //<---$scope.popShows is a declaration and you don't need to declare this variable beforehand.
   })
   ```
3. Now you need to declare the method PopularShows.all() in your services.js file. In ionic you can do that with .factory('YOUR_METHOD_NAME', function($http){...}). $http means your method uses http request. In my case:

   ```
   .factory('PopularShows', function($http){
   // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array
     return {
       all: function() {
          return $http.get('YOUR_API_URL');
       },
       get: function(popShowId) {
       // Simple index lookup
         return popShows[popShowId];
       }
     }
   });
   ```
4. Handle the popShows variable which is a JSON list in the html file. In my case:

   ```
   <ion-view view-title="Popular">
    <ion-content>
     <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="popShow in popShows" type="item-text-wrap">
       <h2>{{popShow.name}}</h2>
       <p>{{popShow.popularity}}</p>
       <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>

       <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="remove(popShow)">
         Delete
        </ion-option-button>
       </ion-item>
     </ion-list>    
    </ion-content>
   </ion-view>
   ```

   The ng-repeat"popShow in popShows" will iterate over the list.

**Conclusion:**

As you can see 'PopularShows' is the method name in the services.js which is called from the controllers.js file. 
PopularShows.all() makes the API call and returns it to controller.
The controller then declares a variable ($scope.popShows) which is used in the html tab-popular.